# chef recipe NoMethodError undefined method `access' for Chef::Resource::S3File

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I am trying to download files from s3 on ec2 instances and getting below error. I have created the databag item access.json giving the keys. Please help

```
================================================================================
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/s3_file/recipes/default.rb
================================================================================

NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `access' for Chef::Resource::S3File

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/s3_file/recipes/default.rb:13:in `block in from_file'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/s3_file/recipes/default.rb:10:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/s3_file/recipes/default.rb:

  6:  #
  7:  # All rights reserved - Do Not Redistribute
  8:  #
  9:  ws = data_bag_item('cred1', 'access.json')
 10:  s3_file 'xxxxxxxxxxx' do
 11:    bucket 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 12:    remote_path 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
 13>>   aws_access_key_id  access.json['aws_access_key_id']
 14:    aws_secret_access_key access.json['aws_secret_access_key']
 15:    region 'us-west-1'
 16:    owner "root"
 17:    group "root"
 18:    mode 0777
 19:  end
 20:  
 21:
```

access.json is the databag item

actual recipe is

```
ws = data_bag_item('cred1', 'access.json')
s3_file 'xxxxxxxxx' do
  bucket 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  remote_path 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
  aws_access_key_id  access.json['aws_access_key_id']
  aws_secret_access_key access.json['aws_secret_access_key']
  region 'us-west-1'
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode 0777
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following line:

```
aws_access_key_id  access.json['aws_access_key_id']
```

is there a variable named `access` somewhere?

You're retrieving the data bag item, but storing it in a variable named `ws`. Given that, you might want to change the above line (and the one following it) like so:

```
aws_access_key_id  ws['aws_access_key_id']
aws_secret_access_key ws['aws_secret_access_key']
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. Now its giving below error:
NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `region' for Chef::Resource::S3File

If I remove it then it is giving below error:

    RestClient::ResourceNotFound
    ----------------------------
    404 Resource Not Found

Comment: The `s3_file` cookbook does not support a `region` attribute, so this is possibly an error with permissions on S3 or incorrect credentials. I'd recommend reading the [documentation on the s3_file cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/s3_file).